# Intuitive explanation of FOIL's gain in Rule-based classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining

I encounter the formula for calculating FOIL's gain as below:

$$FOIL's\space gain = p_0(log_2(\frac{p_1}{p_1+n_1}) - log_2(\frac{p_0}{p_0+n_0}))$$

unlike Information gain or Gini index used to measure the purity of the split chunk in Decision Tree, there are plenty of material that explain the concepts of these measures. For example, Information gain comes from the concept of entropy, and Gini calculates the total variance of the Benoulli trials.

but for this measure, I do not quite see what it measures. It looks somewhat like calculating Information gain after adding a new rule to the rule set, I do not know why we have to multiply it with  $p_0$.

anyone has an intuitive explanation about this? thank you.